# Android studio, import project into CVS repository

Tags: android-studio, cvs, keyword-substitution

I have fully functional project in Android studio. I want to import this project to CVS repositories and then check it out on another PC. 
While importing to CVS there is only one option to choose: KEYWORD SUBSTITUTION, but i could't find good explanation what is the best option.

I don't know where the problem is. If in import into CVS or check out.

Only errors i get after building the project:

> C:\Android\EsoCRM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Whats the best way to manage CVS repositories in Android studio?

Comment: Keyword substitution in CVS and SVN etc. allows you to insert things like Author and Last Updated as variables. Documentation for Keyword Substitution is at http://cvsman.com/cvs-1.12.12/cvs_100.php#SEC100. I can't tell from your error output but I don't believe that's your issue. I'd probably recommend Googling along the lines of "Version Control System in Android Studio". Possibly with CVS but Git is by far more popular and you're more likely to find more information that will remain relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a build problem, possibly related to your CVS setup.

If you look at the error, it is referencing `appcompat-v7` in the "build\intermediates\exploded-aar" folder. Review the following:

1. You should not include anything in the "build" folder in the repo. These are generated at the time you do a build, for the system where the build is being performed. Exclude everything in the "build" folder from the repo. (You should also exclude all "*.iml" files for the same reason.)
2. Clean your project. If you copied files here, or if you had a bad cached file, then you will need to remove them and try again.
3. Delete the ".caches" folder in gradle, if necessary. Sometimes old cached files are out of date, but gradle does not update them. You may need to manually delete them and do an update.